# Flutter Firebase: Compare two timestamps using conditional statements

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get two Timestamps from firebase and use the conditional statement but it keeps telling me

> The operator '>=' isn't defined for the type 'Timestamp'.
> Try defining the operator '>='.dartundefined_operator

The code

```
Timestamp dynamicTime = snapshot.data?["Timestamp"];
Timestamp staticTime = snapshot.data?["TimestampDeparture"];
if (dynamicTime >= staticTime){...}
```

How do I do this comparison statement? Any help, please?

Answer (score 1):

The [Timestamp class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Timestamp-class.html) implements [Comparable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Comparable-class.html), so it has a method [compareTo()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Timestamp/compareTo.html) which does what you want.  According to the Comparable interface, it will return -1, 0, or 1 based on the ordering of the two objects being compared.

```
if (timestamp1.compareTo(timestamp2) > 0) {
    // This means that timestamp1 is greater than timestamp2
}
```

Comment: Google's `package:basics` has a [`ComparableBasics`](https://pub.dev/documentation/basics/latest/comparable_basics/ComparableBasics.html) extension that provides `operator <`, `operator >`, `operator <=` and `operator >=` for `Comparable` objects.